# Is there a lightweight signal-slot implementation with basic reflection?

Tags: c++

**Background**

I need to implement a dynamically-configurable data-processing toolkit. There will be several data processing entities, which can be combined to a data-flow graph by using a GUI tool.
The idea is similiar to Direct Show filter graphs (GraphEdit) or Apple's Quartz Composer.

The GUI tool will store graph definitions in a file. When the actual processing is started, this definition file will be read, and data processing objects have to be created and connected at runtime.

I have used Qt's signals and slots for similiar problems before, but this time the main program does not have any GUI. So I'd like to use something less bloated.

**Question**

What is the easiest way to have signal/slot functionality with basic reflection, without using Qt?

I need to define a fixed number of slot types (each with a certain predefined function signature).
For example, there will be an image-consuming slot, taking an image object as parameter, or a slot just taking an int as parameter.

At runtime, I need to iterate through all signals/slots and connect them dynamically.

I do not need to inspect Slot/Signal Parameters at runtime. It sufficient to have a fixed number of parameter sets. It would be ok to put some kind of hint in the slot's name to identify the signature type.

I know that boost ships with signal2, which provides signal/slot functionality. But whats the fastest way to implement reflection? Should I build my own set of macro-hacks?

Comment: You are aware that Qt's signals and slots are in [QtCore](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtcore.html) **not** in [QtGui](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtgui.html) and therefore do not need to `#include` or link to the GUI libraries at all, yes?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but it seems [cpgf](http://www.kbasm.com/cpgf-index.html) has all features you need (reflection and signal/slot).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use Qt to develop non-GUI tool. AFAIR, doxygen uses Qt. But I didn't use Qt by myself yet. 

Also a suggestion is that you should NOT implement you reflection system unless you are ready to invest a lot of your time and energy. You may implement a dirty and quick reflection system in your app but then you may find you need more time to maintain or improve it as your app growing. 
Also forget macros for reflection. Macros are too ugly and too error prone. 

For my cpgf library (I'm the author), I'm not ready to promote it yet because it's quite new (less than one year) and not as mature as other library. However, I really appreciate if any real projects use it to verify it works in real world than just works in unit tests. And I would like to give necessary assistance to the projects for bug fixing or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Boost also has an implementation of signal and slots
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/signals.html